# PHP Strange Whitespace is created while writing files. (blocks CSS)

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, whitespace, fwrite

I'm trying to save code via PHP in a *.php file to run it later in an iframe.

**Problem:**

For some reason the CSS isn't working (HTML + JS are working!), after some experimenting i noticed that the spaces in the file aren't really saperating the CSS code (replacing them with regular keyboard spaces fixed the problem), so i tried the find the difference, but their unicodes were the same (UTF-8: 20).
Even the strict PHP operator (===) says they're the same and 'ord()' returns 32 for both.
As far as I can tell is it created while writing the file.

**Example:** [**>JSFiddle<**](https://jsfiddle.net/ccvk0kc0/6/)

**HTML:**

```
<!--head--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<textarea name="HTML" [...] spellcheck="false">[HTML in the JSFiddle]</textarea>
<textarea name="CSS" [...] spellcheck="false">[CSS in the JSFiddle]</textarea>
<textarea name="JS" [...] spellcheck="false">[JS in the JSFiddle]</textarea>
```

**PHP:**

```
//mb_internal_encoding() ---> "UTF-8"
$php = fopen($myPath.'/'.$_POST['name'].'.php', 'w');
fwrite($php, '<html><head><style type="text/css">'.$_POST['CSS'].'</style><script type="text/javascript">'.$_POST['JS'].'</script></head><body style="margin: 0;">'.$_POST['HTML'].'</body></html>');
//adding "\xEF\xBB\xBF" doesn't help (all files are in UTF-8)
fclose($php);
```

**Questions:**

- Why are those spaces different?
- How can I fix it?
- Has someone an regex for replacing whitespace with a normal space (/\s+/g generates lots of "Â" and spaces)?

**UPDATE 1:**

All data is in UTF-8:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['HTML'], 'UTF-8, ASCII', true); //UTF-8
echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['CSS'], 'UTF-8, ASCII', true); //UTF-8
echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['JS'], 'UTF-8, ASCII', true); //UTF-8
```

**Thank you!** *- Minding*

Comment: Regex for the whitespace part: `$str = preg_replace('/[\s\pZ]+/u', ' ', $str);` - \s is Posix whitespace, \pZ is Unicode whitespace, and modifier /u is to make PCRE understand UTF-8.

Comment: @TinoDidriksen I've tried _everything_ to compare those spaces and find the difference and they seemed to be the same. Then I thought that it has to be the 'fwrite' function or something. After reading your comment i gave it a shot and i couldn't believe it, it worked perfectly fine, **thanks man!!** If you wanna write an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex for the whitespace part: `$str = preg_replace('/[\s\pZ]+/u', ' ', $str);` - \s is Posix whitespace, \pZ is Unicode whitespace, and modifier /u is to make PCRE understand UTF-8.

The fact that it worked means that the actual data must have contained some other whitespace. Maybe it is the infamous NBSP (Unicode U+00A0, UTF-8 0xc8a0). But would need to see a hexdump of the original data - not the JSFiddle snippet.

Comment: How do I do a hexdump? 'bin2hex' returned 20 (as 'ord' before).

Comment: `bin2hex` is fine...hell if I know then. Maybe there is an output filter doing crazy conversions? Or, for kicks, try opening the file with mode `wb` instead of just `w`. Also, the UTF-8 BOM 0xefbbbf should always be removed from all data.

Comment: Well, I'll just leave it as it is for now. I mean it's working :D Thanks a lot.